# Unable to get message in priority sequence Spring camel rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, apache-camel, amqp

I am a beginner in using `spring camel rabbitmq`.

I am able to set message priority in message header by setting it in exchange out headers on the producer side, like this :

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("rabbitmq.PRIORITY", 1);
```

BUT while consuming the messages they dont come in there order of priority. HELP !!

I can see in web interface of `rabbitmq` that priority header in appropriately set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the issue.
problem was that I was not able to set **x-max-priority** using `camel` endpoints.
Need to add it in **queueArgsConfigurer** option in queue.
To do this we need to implement ArgsConfigurer interface like this :

```
@Component(value="QueueArgsConfigurer")
public class QueueArgsConfigurer implements ArgsConfigurer {
@Override
public void configurArgs(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("x-max-priority", 3);
}

}
```

And add to queue endpoint queueArgsConfigurer option like this:
    queueArgsConfigurer=#QueueArgsConfigurer
Since I am using `spring` I get the QueueArgsConfigurer by its bean name.

Answer (score 1):

Please carefully read the "Interaction with consumers" section of [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html). You should also search for an answer on the [RabbitMQ Users List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) or post your question there if it has not been asked.

Comment: what if the messages are already queued up and then i attach a consumer to it. Then should it prioritize  the messages? I am not publishing the messages subsequently.