# Apache Camel RabbitMQ X-Expires Argument

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am having some trouble declaring an exchange and temporary queue using Camel RabbitMQ component with the x-expires argument specified. My endpoint looks like this:

```
rabbitmq:MyExchange?args=arg.queue.x-expires=10000&autoDelete=true&exchangeType=direct&routingKey=MyRoutingKey
```

and I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: args as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.util.Map with value arg.queue.x-expires=1000
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:618) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:649) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:491) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:501) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:254) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:309) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:297) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:248) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:34) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:126) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:706) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    ... 3 more
```

Looking at the RabbitMQ Camel component [documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/release/2.23.1/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/docs/rabbitmq-component.adoc), I find that the args requires me to specify a `Map<String, Object>` as the arguments, but I cannot find where in the Camel documentation to do this. Is there a way to specify the expiration time of the queue so it is automatically deleted/expired after the time has elapsed?

Comment: Ah we can likely improve this in camel-rabbitmq component. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel

Comment: @ClausIbsen i already made a comment in github it was ignored https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/2010

Comment: The only way i found currently is to use QueueArgsConfigurer (deprecated) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582445/unable-to-get-message-in-priority-sequence-spring-camel-rabbitmq